# Why can’t git log specific range of commits on a fetched or remote branch?

Tags: git, github

I cloned the git repo from https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager, and then

```
$ git fetch origin android-tv:android-tv-my
From https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
 * [new branch]        android-tv -> android-tv-my
 
$ git log --oneline android-tv-my
35f358f2 (origin/android-tv, android-tv-my) Add basic navigation compatibility for TV
c409873f Merge pull request #823 from Pavneet-Sing/master
f64d3ffc Clarity , optimization, doc fix
df3cf58f Revert "Add compatibility with AS 3.0"
f18e39f5 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
85d99dd2 Add compatibility with AS 3.0
5d9e9aa8 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
8ae5854c Sanitize input from ZipViewer and directory opening paths
67d9833c Update strings.xml
2d99040c Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
c4e338bc Secure Amaze against external intent injection
7f352b78 Merge pull request #813 from preet90/lg-g3-download-issue
679af0c4 replaced maxline with single line. There is an issue with ellipsize middle if used along with maxline in the old android versions.
b6e19689 Merge branch 'EmmanuelMess-lambda-feature'
c747234c Fix merge conflicts
a315e530 Minor fix while loading files from cloud
bbce5709 Merge branch 'EmmanuelMess-fix-loadingpaste'
644e4b28 Change intermediate string from copy prepare dialog
353166cd Merge branch 'fix-loadingpaste' of https://github.com/EmmanuelMess/AmazeFileManager into EmmanuelMess-fix-loadingpaste
21d29129 Merge pull request #789 from EmmanuelMess/fix-asyncloading
003518c0 Remove redundant code
404d7ba7 Reduced usage of deprecated file lister functions
27b7346a Separated and deprecated methods that return file lists
6fbe4940 HybridFileParcelable instantly into LayoutElementParcelable in LoadFilesListTask
65aa41ba Reordered list*() functions to coincide with calls in LoadFilesListTask
957f0121 Cleaned RootHelper.getFilesList() and fixed possible crash
d8bd6047 Reduced possible creation of hybrid file in LoadFilesListTask
91349ac5 Simplified ifs in LodeFilesListTask
```

I want to only list the commits between 003518c0 and 85d99dd2, but got:

```
$ git log --oneline android-tv-my 003518c0..85d99dd2
35f358f2 (origin/android-tv, android-tv-my) Add basic navigation compatibility for TV
c409873f Merge pull request #823 from Pavneet-Sing/master
f64d3ffc Clarity , optimization, doc fix
df3cf58f Revert "Add compatibility with AS 3.0"
f18e39f5 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
85d99dd2 Add compatibility with AS 3.0
5d9e9aa8 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
8ae5854c Sanitize input from ZipViewer and directory opening paths
67d9833c Update strings.xml
2d99040c Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
c4e338bc Secure Amaze against external intent injection
7f352b78 Merge pull request #813 from preet90/lg-g3-download-issue
679af0c4 replaced maxline with single line. There is an issue with ellipsize middle if used along with maxline in the old android versions.
b6e19689 Merge branch 'EmmanuelMess-lambda-feature'
c747234c Fix merge conflicts
a315e530 Minor fix while loading files from cloud
bbce5709 Merge branch 'EmmanuelMess-fix-loadingpaste'
644e4b28 Change intermediate string from copy prepare dialog
353166cd Merge branch 'fix-loadingpaste' of https://github.com/EmmanuelMess/AmazeFileManager into EmmanuelMess-fix-loadingpaste
21d29129 Merge pull request #789 from EmmanuelMess/fix-asyncloading
404d7ba7 Reduced usage of deprecated file lister functions
27b7346a Separated and deprecated methods that return file lists
6fbe4940 HybridFileParcelable instantly into LayoutElementParcelable in LoadFilesListTask
65aa41ba Reordered list*() functions to coincide with calls in LoadFilesListTask
957f0121 Cleaned RootHelper.getFilesList() and fixed possible crash
d8bd6047 Reduced possible creation of hybrid file in LoadFilesListTask
91349ac5 Simplified ifs in LodeFilesListTask
50ff1969 Simplified HybridFile.generateMode() code
c2155239 Used ConcurrentRadixTree in lib to rewrite hidden files code
ba9fea2a Simplified LoadFilesListTask.addTo()
0908357e Reduced null initializations LoadFilesListTask
8e12077c BitmapDrawables->Drawables, reducing object creation
b4a3fe6b Replaced static method with constructor for LayoutElementParcelable
5caee3dc Replaced method by Java method in LodeFilesListTask
406e6755 Simplified cloud storage switch in LoadFilesListTask
0761de09 Deleted unnecessary onProgressUpdate loading files and returns null on exception in LodeFilesListTask
2e9f4535 Simplified some code and fixed possible bug in LodeFilesListTask
3f3b80d5 Used retrolambda in utils
8b7d1925 Used retrolambda in ui
b91cf16b Used retrolambda in fragments
288d8095 Use retrolambda in RootHelper
4e8f903b Used retrolambdas in asyncs
7fe6f328 Used retrolambda in adapters
95e8bdc5 Used retrolambda in activities
9664d032 Added retrolambda
5a2d1490 Shows indeterminate ProgressDialog while creating copy tree
```

What’s wrong?
And also got unexpected on origin/android-tv :

```
$ git log --oneline origin/android-tv 003518c0..85d99dd2
35f358f2 (origin/android-tv, android-tv-my) Add basic navigation compatibility for TV
c409873f Merge pull request #823 from Pavneet-Sing/master
f64d3ffc Clarity , optimization, doc fix
df3cf58f Revert "Add compatibility with AS 3.0"
f18e39f5 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
85d99dd2 Add compatibility with AS 3.0
5d9e9aa8 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
8ae5854c Sanitize input from ZipViewer and directory opening paths
67d9833c Update strings.xml
2d99040c Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/TeamAmaze/AmazeFileManager
c4e338bc Secure Amaze against external intent injection
7f352b78 Merge pull request #813 from preet90/lg-g3-download-issue
679af0c4 replaced maxline with single line. There is an issue with ellipsize middle if used along with maxline in the old android versions.
b6e19689 Merge branch 'EmmanuelMess-lambda-feature'
c747234c Fix merge conflicts
a315e530 Minor fix while loading files from cloud
bbce5709 Merge branch 'EmmanuelMess-fix-loadingpaste'
644e4b28 Change intermediate string from copy prepare dialog
353166cd Merge branch 'fix-loadingpaste' of https://github.com/EmmanuelMess/AmazeFileManager into EmmanuelMess-fix-loadingpaste
21d29129 Merge pull request #789 from EmmanuelMess/fix-asyncloading
404d7ba7 Reduced usage of deprecated file lister functions
27b7346a Separated and deprecated methods that return file lists
6fbe4940 HybridFileParcelable instantly into LayoutElementParcelable in LoadFilesListTask
65aa41ba Reordered list*() functions to coincide with calls in LoadFilesListTask
957f0121 Cleaned RootHelper.getFilesList() and fixed possible crash
d8bd6047 Reduced possible creation of hybrid file in LoadFilesListTask
91349ac5 Simplified ifs in LodeFilesListTask
50ff1969 Simplified HybridFile.generateMode() code
c2155239 Used ConcurrentRadixTree in lib to rewrite hidden files code
ba9fea2a Simplified LoadFilesListTask.addTo()
0908357e Reduced null initializations LoadFilesListTask
8e12077c BitmapDrawables->Drawables, reducing object creation
b4a3fe6b Replaced static method with constructor for LayoutElementParcelable
5caee3dc Replaced method by Java method in LodeFilesListTask
406e6755 Simplified cloud storage switch in LoadFilesListTask
0761de09 Deleted unnecessary onProgressUpdate loading files and returns null on exception in LodeFilesListTask
2e9f4535 Simplified some code and fixed possible bug in LodeFilesListTask
3f3b80d5 Used retrolambda in utils
8b7d1925 Used retrolambda in ui
b91cf16b Used retrolambda in fragments
288d8095 Use retrolambda in RootHelper
4e8f903b Used retrolambdas in asyncs
7fe6f328 Used retrolambda in adapters
95e8bdc5 Used retrolambda in activities
9664d032 Added retrolambda
5a2d1490 Shows indeterminate ProgressDialog while creating copy tree
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have asked for is to list all the commits on `origin/android-tv` *or* between those two revisions.  Consequently, you have probably gotten more than you wanted.

If you know that those two revisions are in the history of that remote tracking branch, then just use the revision range that you've specified.  If you're unsure and want to see only the revisions that are in both ranges, you can write this:

```
$ git log --oneline 003518c0..$(git merge-base 85d99dd2 origin/android-tv)
```

That will find the values from `003518c0` to the common ancestor of `85d99dd2` and `origin/android-tv`.  If that remote-tracking branch doesn't contain anything in that range, then you'll get an empty result.